# Reaching to Collection that each item of it is a Collection

Tags: c#, performance

I have `Room` and `Bed` classes in EF which each `Room` have some `Bed`(s).I have a `Collection` of `Room`s that I retrieved from EF `context`;I use this code to reach to all `Bed`s in `Collection` of `Room`s (`myRooms`):

```
IEnumerable<Room> myRooms=...
IEnumerable<Bed> bedsInMyRoom=context.Beds.AsEnumerable();
foreach (IEnumerable<Bed> beds in myRooms.Beds)
     {
       if(beds!=null && beds.Any())
          bedsInMyRoom=bedsInMyRoom.Concat(beds);
     }
```

Is there any better way in performance to do this?

Comment: Does your snippet work?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan excuse me,I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just want:

```
var beds = rooms.SelectMany(room => room.Beds);
```

(That's assuming there's a `Beds` property in `Room`. You're not using it in the original code snippet.)

If the rooms were fetched without the bed details, you *may* need else - please let us know.

Comment: @majidgeek: Well in your original snippet, you never used the `Room.Beds` property - you just iterate over the room itself. That is surprising - if there *is* a `Beds` property, you should use it.